# Esse tipo de resposta como aceita é válido?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Vejam essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309804/como-obter-a-hora-pela-base-de-dados-usando-o-entity-framework

Obviamente que não responde a pergunta, me parece mais um "vota em mim aí pra me ajudar"

O que a comunidade acha?

Comment: Parece concordar com você, até porque ao que parece as contas envolvidas estavam utilizando deste artifício para manipulação de votos e reputação, sendo banidos - um deles, pelo menos, o outro não sei se também foi ou se ele mesmo excluiu a conta.

Comment: Ps.: pergunta removida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Era isso mesmo. Eu acho que há casos que uma resposta simples pode ser útil, essa mesma dava pra pensar, mas neste caso estava havendo um outro problema, havia má intenção ou algum outro problema que desqualificava como uma tentativa válida de responder, ou seja, o problema era mais embaixo do que pergunta.

Em outros casos é tênue, é aquela coisa de interpretação. As vezes eu sei o que é melhor fazer.

Answer (score 6):

Para quem não pode ver publicações deletadas, segue aqui o conteúdo da pergunta:

[image: pergunta]

Respostas:

[image: respostas]

O que era o conteúdo da resposta ocultada:

[image: Conteúdo]